# Maximum users of shared folder on my Vista machine

Tags: windows

I share a Vista computer folder with about 25 people (not concurrently) every now and then I get a message that I exceeded my limit, so I reboot my vista machine and all is well for a little while. I read where I am limited to 10 concurrent users, I doubt if 10 people are on at any one time.
If I have that shared folder mapped on the users computers does that count toward my 10?
If someone access that shared folder then gets out of it, do they remain in the count toward my 10?
Is there a way of clearing this count other that a reboot?

I read that W7 allows up to 20 concurrent users, better but not enough. If I were to put my shared folder on server I would then have to get enought licenses to cover all my users correct?